# Gridviews inside Repeater

Tags: asp.net, gridview, repeater

I have a repeater on my page, linked with a datasource who fills the repeater with teams. My goal is to create a header for each team and a gridview for each team to modify the players in each team.

Problem: the datasource of the gridview needs a PK of the team to get the appropriate players out of the database. How can I pass them?

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="odsTeam">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <h1>
            <%# Eval("name") %>
            with maximum of
            <%# Eval("st_max") %>
            players.</h1>

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="participant_id"
            DataSourceID="odsParticipant">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="participant_id" HeaderText="participant_id" InsertVisible="False"
                    ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="participant_id" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="participant_category_id" HeaderText="participant_category_id"
                    SortExpression="participant_category_id" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="team_id" HeaderText="team_id" SortExpression="team_id" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="room_id" HeaderText="room_id" SortExpression="room_id" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="delegation_id" HeaderText="delegation_id" SortExpression="delegation_id" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="first_name" HeaderText="first_name" SortExpression="first_name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="last_name" HeaderText="last_name" SortExpression="last_name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="date_of_birth" HeaderText="date_of_birth" SortExpression="date_of_birth" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="gender" HeaderText="gender" SortExpression="gender" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="identification_number" HeaderText="identification_number"
                    SortExpression="identification_number" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="photo_url" HeaderText="photo_url" SortExpression="photo_url" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="squad_number" HeaderText="squad_number" SortExpression="squad_number" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="length" HeaderText="length" SortExpression="length" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="weight" HeaderText="weight" SortExpression="weight" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsTeam" runat="server" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}"
    OnSelecting="odsTeam_Selecting" SelectMethod="GetTeamsByDelegationID" TypeName="TeamBLL">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="delegation_id" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>

<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsParticipant" runat="server" DeleteMethod="Delete" InsertMethod="Insert"
            OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="GetParticipantsByTeamID"
            TypeName="ERASTableAdapters.tbl_participantTableAdapter" 
    UpdateMethod="Update" onselecting="odsParticipant_Selecting">
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Original_participant_id" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Original_participant_category_id" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Original_team_id" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Original_room_id" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Original_delegation_id" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Original_first_name" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Original_last_name" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Original_date_of_birth" Type="DateTime" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Original_gender" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Original_identification_number" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Original_photo_url" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Original_squad_number" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Original_length" Type="Decimal" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Original_weight" Type="Decimal" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="participant_category_id" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="team_id" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="room_id" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="delegation_id" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="first_name" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="last_name" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="date_of_birth" Type="DateTime" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="gender" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="identification_number" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="photo_url" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="squad_number" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="length" Type="Decimal" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="weight" Type="Decimal" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Original_participant_id" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Original_participant_category_id" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Original_team_id" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Original_room_id" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Original_delegation_id" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Original_first_name" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Original_last_name" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Original_date_of_birth" Type="DateTime" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Original_gender" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Original_identification_number" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Original_photo_url" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Original_squad_number" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Original_length" Type="Decimal" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Original_weight" Type="Decimal" />
            </UpdateParameters>
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="team_id" Type="Int32" />
            </SelectParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="participant_category_id" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="team_id" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="room_id" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="delegation_id" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="first_name" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="last_name" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="date_of_birth" Type="DateTime" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="gender" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="identification_number" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="photo_url" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="squad_number" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="length" Type="Decimal" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="weight" Type="Decimal" />
            </InsertParameters>
        </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know one work around that I have used one time...

First of all put your hidden field in your repeater and bind your id and then in your gridview datasource provide a hidden field control as a select parameter:

```
 <h1>
        <%# Eval("name") %>
        with maximum of
        <%# Eval("st_max") %>
        players.</h1>
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdfId" Value='<%# Eval("TeamId") %>' />

    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsTeam" runat="server" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}"
        OnSelecting="odsTeam_Selecting" SelectMethod="GetTeamsByDelegationID" TypeName="TeamBLL">
        <SelectParameters>
             <asp:ControlParameter PropertyName="value" Name="delegation_id" ControlID="hdfId" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Comment: Thank you! One more question: is there a way to modify your gridview in Design mode because the repeater doesn't show the gridview in Design mode in VS2008 :D

Comment: no you can't do this in repeater. but one way, you can take this gridview to another page, and modify there and then again copy that source from there to this page.